# How to encode and shorten hash for url safety?

Tags: java, url, hash, base64, codec

I use SHA-512 to hash a token, which results in a 128 character string. How can I encode it so that it is shorter but still URL safe (no need to escape like '+' or '&')?

Hex and Base32 are both suboptimal, and Base64 is unsafe. I don't want to hack up a custom Base62 codec, as that will only become a maintenance burden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 8 added Base64 encoders, with different flavors.  See java.util.Base64

For example:

```
Base64.getUrlEncoder().encode(...);
```

Comment: Whaddaya know, you're right! The Google one is better designed (en-/decoder encapsulation, CharSequence instead of String) but still I'll use the built-in one, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Google has you covered:

```
com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding#base64Url
```

This is an efficient Base64 codec that only uses url-safe characters. It will produce a String with a length of 88 characters for a SHA512 hash.